# Can anyone explain what does this query means?

Tags: oracle

What would be the output?? And please explain the below coalesce statement.

"COALESCE(NULL, :RG) IS NULL"

Comment: What is the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COALESCE` returns the first not null value, so if you pass 2 arguments and the first is `NULL`, you will receive the second one if is not null.

In a `where` the espression you pasted is equal to `:RG IS NULL`.

Maybe coalesce is here for some compatibility issue? Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

The `coalesce` statement is totally useless. You could also write it like this:

```
:RG IS NULL
```

And that simply checks if the `:rg` parameter passed in is null or not. This would be placed in a `where` clause or a `case` switch.

Comment: So useless that I suspect tool-generated code upon seeing it.